# Broadcasting logical operators along a different axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and a Series:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.3, (5, 4)).astype(bool))
ser = pd.Series(np.random.binomial(1, 0.3, 5).astype(bool))
```

```
df
Out: 
       0      1      2      3
0  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2   True  False   True  False
3  False   True  False  False
4  False   True   True   True

ser
Out: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

I want to compare each column against the Series row by row to see if both elements are True. The result should be:

```
       0      1      2      3
0  False   True  False  False
1  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False
3  False   True  False  False
4  False  False  False  False
```

I can do this with `df.mul(ser, axis=0)` but it raises a warning:

> UserWarning: evaluating in Python space because the '*' operator is
>   not supported by numexpr for the bool dtype, use '&' instead

I am guessing this would slow down the operation. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this computation is array-based (no alignment of index labels necessary),
you could compute this with NumPy arrays and NumPy broadcasting:

```
np.logical_and(df.values, ser.values[:, None])
```

---

Here is a speed comparison of a few alternatives:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N, M = 500, 400
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.3, (N, M)).astype(bool))
ser = pd.Series(np.random.binomial(1, 0.3, N).astype(bool))
```

---

```
In [60]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.logical_and(df.values, ser.values[:, None]), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 93.4 µs per loop

In [51]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.values * ser.values[:,None], columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.4 µs per loop

In [47]: %timeit df.mul(ser, axis=0)
UserWarning: evaluating in Python space because the '*' operator is not supported by numexpr for the bool dtype, use '&' instead
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop

In [46]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x & ser)
10 loops, best of 3: 135 ms per loop
```